# Is there a way to revert to the built-in function after overwritting it using Unprotect

Tags: functions, packages

When using Unprotect, we can overwrite a functions definition:

```
Unprotect[Sqrt]
Sqrt[x_]="blahblah"
Protect[Sqrt]
```

Once this is done, can we revert to the built-in version of Sqrt?

Answer (score 12):

```
Unprotect[Sqrt];
Sqrt[x_] = "blahblah";
Protect[Sqrt];

Sqrt[2]
```

> blahblah

```
Unprotect[Sqrt];
ClearAll[Sqrt];
Protect[Sqrt];

Sqrt[2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the previous definition and use built-in function in further operation, you can use `ParallelEvaluate`

```
    Unprotect[Sqrt];
    Sqrt[x_] = "blahblah";
    Protect[Sqrt];
    Sqrt[4]
    (*"blahblah"*)
    First@ParallelEvaluate[Sqrt[4]]
    (*2*)
```

Comment: That works for a completely different reason, which is that your current context isn't distributed to the parallel kernels. Considering that a function may be defined for use in Parallelize[] or ParallelMap[] or ParallelEvaluate[] and contexts would be distributed, your answer would fail. And if there was no intent for parallelization, your answer is excessive. Why launch kernel for something that can simply be cleared off and return to the value set by a context defined prior to yours?