# How to understand the difference between Sqrt and Log after ClearAll them

Tags: evaluation, kernel, attributes

I came across [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61474/6468), here I change the last line of the code

```
Unprotect[Sqrt];
Sqrt[x_] = "blahblah";
Protect[Sqrt];
Sqrt[2]
```

> "blahblah"

```
Unprotect[Sqrt];
ClearAll[Sqrt];
Protect[Sqrt];
Sqrt[{1, 2, 3}]
```

> {1, Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3]}

And I do the same for `Log`

```
Unprotect[Log];
Log[x_] = "blahblah";
Protect[Log];
Log[2]
```

> "blahblah"

```
Unprotect[Log];
ClearAll[Log];
Protect[Log];
Log[{1, 2}]
```

> Log[{1, 2}]

Since I've `ClearAll` the definitions *and* attributes of `Sqrt` and `Log`, and neither of them have `Listable` attributes.

```
Attributes[{Sqrt, Log}]
```

> {{Protected}, {Protected}}

So why is `Sqrt` still `Listable` while `Log` is not? Do I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leaving aside the wisdom of modifying System functions this is an interesting question.

I would not have been surprised to see this behavior had the input list been packed as I have already learned about low-level optimizations on packed arrays.  See:

- [Block attributes of Equal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3261/121)

However that does not appear to be the issue here since (typed in) `{1, 2, 3}` is not packed.  Apparently the "listable" behavior of `Sqrt` is not (only) implemented in terms of the attribute [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html).  As an example here is function without `Listable` that still threads over lists:

```
f[x_List] := f /@ x

f[{1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {f[1], f[2], f[3]}
> ```

Leonid writes about Listability here:

- [Two ways of map a function on the list: Which one is faster?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35150/121)

Quoting:

> There are two types of listability - the one in built-in functions,
>   which pushes threading into the kernel and is fast, and the top-level
>   one (setting Listable for some functions by the user).
>
> You can not achieve built-in listability by simply setting a
>   `Listable` attribute. The reason is that, while the end result is the
>   same - automatic threading over lists, the underlying mechanisms to
>   achieve it are different for built-ins vs user-defined. When a
>   built-in `Listable` function (particularly numerical) is passed lists
>   as arguments, it dispatches to the special branch which internally
>   runs the loop, and returns a list of results. So, for a built-in
>   function, `Listable` is rather a signal to pick the internal branch
>   which deals with lists automatically.

It seems that the absence of `Listable` does not prevent this "internal branch" from being used.

Comment: I think in this case, you make in `Listable`,because trace it will give me `{f[{1,2,3}],f/@{1,2,3},{f[1],f[2],f[3]}}`.

Comment: @luyuwuli But `f` does not have the `Listable` attribute, it only behaves (somewhat) like it does, and that was my point.

Comment: According to your edit, did you mean that there are lower-level map function implemented in the kernel so that it can auto-thread even without the `Listable` attributes?

Comment: @luyuwuli I am not the one who wrote that, Leonid Shifrin is, but as I understand it, yes.

Comment: I always understood the `Listable` attribute in these cases as mainly a courtesy to user code rather than a requirement for proper evaluation. After all, if a function behaves as if `Listable`, it's not really helpful if the attribute is missing, but you can of course always have a function with specialized definitions for different types of inputs regardless of that. Or, perhaps `Sqrt` implements an explicit loop over depth-1 lists, but not for higher-dimensional structures, so that it is part specialized, and part top-level `Listable`. This would be a reasonable optimization, IMO.